# Is it possible to encrypt data with two public keys?

Tags: encryption

Can we encrypt data with two public keys and the encrypted data only needs one private key to decrypt once encrypted?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the traditional approach of producing a ciphertext that consists of two separate encryptions (one with the first public key, one with the second)?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, we can encrypt with two public keys $\text{Pub}_0$ and $\text{Pub}_1$, then  decipher with one private key $\text{Pub}_i$ matching either one of the two public keys. As noted in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/223330), the simplest method is to encipher to both keys, at the expense of doubling the ciphertext size.

But for large plaintext, we'll be using [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), and then there's a bounded size penalty for each recipient. For two keys key pairs $(\text{Pub}_0,\operatorname{Priv}_0)$ and $(\text{Pub}_1,\operatorname{Priv}_1)$, and assuming recipients know if they are recipient $0$ or $1$, the encryption goes:

- draw a random symmetric key $K$
- asymmetrically encrypt $K$ with each public key forming the two $C_i=\operatorname{Enc}(\operatorname{Pub}_i,K)$
- put the results $C_0\mathbin\|C_1$ at start of ciphertext
- symmetrically encrypt the data using $K$ (e.g. with AES-GCM), forming the rest of the ciphertext.

Decryption by recipient $i$ goes

- from the start of the ciphertext $C_0\mathbin\|C_1$ extract $C_i=\operatorname{Enc}(\operatorname{Pub}_i,K)$
- asymmetrically decrypt $K=\operatorname{Dec}(\operatorname{Priv}_i,C_i)$
- symmetrically decrypt the rest of the ciphertext data using $K$, getting the plaintext.

Extensions are possible so that recipients do not need to know their index (by adding a public key identifier to each $C_i$). This is common, e.g. with (Open)[PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy)/[GPG](https://gnupg.org/) asymmetric encryption, when it sends encrypted to several recipients.

A slightly more complex extension allows that while hiding who are the recipients.

Comment: I understand from the question that there should be one private key with multiple public keys, but maybe that's me.

Comment: The question's _"only needs one private key to decrypt"_ does not imply a single private key. And to me, the question's _"two public keys"_ suggests two matching private keys.